# Unrecognized GitHub environment detected - Who created it?

Tags: github, github-actions

I was recently running a GitHub workflow and noticed it was attempting to deploy to an environment that we hadn't had before. I want to know who created that environment, but I cannot track it. Is there a way to find out who created a GitHub environment? Any sort of logs or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **GitHub for organizations**, then you can do the following:

1. Go to your **Organization**.
2. Click on the **Settings** tab.
3. Find the **Archive** section on the left.
4. Click on **Logs**.
5. Then click on **Audit log**.

There you can search and filter for your specific environment.

If you are searching in an **individual GitHub repository**, then follow these steps:

1. Click on your **profile icon** in the upper right.
2. Then go to **Settings**.
3. Find the **Archive** section on the left.
4. Click on **Security log**.

To speed up the search, you can use a filter something like this:

```
repo:your-username/repository-name action:environment.create
```